# Login to Expression Engine outside of site?

Tags: authentication, oauth, expressionengine

Is there a correct way to securely login to an expression engine site outside of the site?

Totally like a Facebook Oauth, but I have not found a way to incorporate Oauth into EE. Or even found out if the current login system would be able to do secure logins without the help of something like Oauth.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had shared the solution you probably found.

Comment: I ended up building my own API endpoints on EE side to handle a call saving a token and returning the token to use later. I don't know if I can share the code, because it was built for a client.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to do this.  However, SolSpace has developed a plugin to do this:
http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/facebook_connect/
It does cost a little money, but really, short of developing a solution yourself, you are not likely to come across a free module for this.

And no, I don't work for them :) but I do have several of their plugins integrated into my sites.

Comment: Yea I have used that before. I am looking to make the membership inside EE be the member you are loggin in as... but from another site than the one EE is installed on. (not using FB)